# SWF loses CLASS data

Tags: actionscript-3

I am having a strange problem when loading external swfs

The swf it's self runs smoothly without problems when directly executed, however, when load, (via embed, loader, uiLoader), it's always the same problem, it returns errors about my AssetMnger Class, which contains different static variables for other classes to use, the error simply states that the variables don't exist

I made a test on the swf, once it's loaded it no longer acknowledges the existence AssetMnger
And simply create a new empty class instead with the same name

So why am i losing this class?
I honestly have no idea why this is happening

Any ideas would be appreciated

UPDATE:

The problem was resolved soon after posting this question
You were right Antoine, i had a preloader containing a class with the same name
Thus there was a slight conflict

I was unaware that when flash treats an embedded SWF classes it does so in respect to the application as a whole and not only to the SWF file it's self

At any rate, thank you for your time

Comment: Please post code of AssetManager and an example of how do you address those static variables within. Also, check if you're actually using static properties, and not re-initialize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a conflict of class definitions. Posting the error could be useful but verify that there is not a different version `AssetMngr` already compiled inside the main SWF. If it's the case recompile all your SWF files or try playing with `LoaderContext.applicationDomain` when loading the SWF files.

For more information, see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd75bf4610ec9e22f43855da312214da1d8f-8000.html .